# All packages in my unity project missing after changing light

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I recently upgraded my project to HDRP. Everything was fine except for some lighting issues. I set the brightness of a point light to 15 lux-100 because for some reason all the lights except for ambient light were extremely dim, then all the sudden something happened and all the packages in the packages folder are gone. Every base unity component except for Transform and some of  the mesh stuff are missing from the project (rigid body, colliders, animator, etc. are all missing). I wasn’t very thorough but everything in the assets folder seemed fine.

Comment: Revert to last known good from your source control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily I had a backup I made the day before, but still, a weird occurrence.